# Generate SSH in Salesforce to connect to external SFTP server

Tags: apex

Thanks for your help!

I have a case where I need to generate an SSH key in Salesforce and share the public key with my client where SFTP server is installed. And then use this SSH for authentication while pushing some files to the external SFTP server.

Is this possible in Salesforce? If yes, how?

Comment: @DavidCheng I knew there was a duplicate somewhere, but I couldn't find it. Great job!

Comment: Hi, pk312. We've marked this question as a duplicate, as it has already been asked a few times before. You'll want to do a [search](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=sftp) for other answers, but they're all basically the same: you can't do this directly, so you'll need a proxy. If you have any further questions, please let us know. If your question is substantially different than the other questions, please [edit] before asking us to reopen your question.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce doesn't support interactive protocols like SFTP or POP3. You would need to write an intermediate proxy to convert an HTTP request to an SFTP request. See also [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170984/salesforce-to-sftp).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DavidCheng. I did not find any thread that spoke about generating SSH using apex. Can someone help?

Comment: @pk312 You can't generate ssh using Apex, which is why you can't find anything about it.